# $\sigma$-finiteness of the set of points that make measurable function equal to \infty

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We saw the following theorem:
 *If $f \in L^{+}$(Space of measurable functions from a set to $[0,\infty]$) and $\int f < \infty$, then $\{x: f(x) = \infty\}$ is a null set and $\{x: f(x) = \infty\}$  is $\sigma$-finite.*

We proved it as follows:
Let $E = \{x : f(x) = \infty \}$, then $E$ is measurable(1.Why?) and for all $n \ge 1$ define $\varphi_n = n\chi_E$ which is a simple function with $0 \leq \varphi_n \leq f$, so

Thus, $\mu E \leq \cfrac{1}{n}\int f $ for all $n \ge 1$. Since $0 \leq \int f < \infty$ it follows that $\mu E = 0$.(2.Why?)

Now let $F= \{x: f(x) > 0 $ and $F_n = \{x: f(x) > \cfrac{1}{n} \}$. Then $\bigcup_{n \ge 1}F_n $. For each $n$, define the simple function $\psi_n = (\cfrac{1}{n})\chi_{F_n}$ with $0 \leq \psi_n \leq f$ so $ \int f \ge \int \psi_n = \cfrac{1}{n}\mu F_n$ from which it follows that $\mu F_n \leq n \int f < \infty$ for all $n$, so $F$ is indeed a $\sigma-finite $ set.

I couldn't understand the proof, especially the $2$ points. Can you explain this proof or give an alternative proof which? Both would be great.

Comment: 1) E is the infinite intersection on $n\geq 0$ of the event $f\geq n$.
2) are you sure ?

Comment: @anonymus, oh it must be $0$, not $\infty$. So, do we take limits to get $0$?

Comment: There's a typo in the proof. You should read "Thus, $\mu E \leq \cfrac{1}{n}\int f $ for all $n \ge 1$. Since $0 \leq \color{red}{\int} f < \infty$ it follows (by letting $n$ go to $\infty$) that $\mu E = 0$."

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, thank you, I edited it.

Comment: Any alternative proofs?

Comment: @Ninja do you still not understand the proof?

Comment: I can follow the proof but I can not prove the theorem without looking at the proof. What I see right now is machinery and can not see the idea behind it.    Actually I still have problems with understanding supremum, liminf.s, unions of intersections of ... sets. The book I follow is Folland's Real Analysis. I am now working on Salamon's Measure and Integration. It would be much more better if you can give me some advice on understanding *what is going on*. Thank you.

Comment: @anonymus, any advice?

Comment: @Ninja , well first, i don't know your definition of sigma-finite. The interesting part to me is that $\mu(f=+\infty) = 0$. If it's $>0$, then the integral of $f$ on the whole space is bigger than the integral of $f$ on $F:=\{ f=+\infty\}$ which is equal to $(+\infty)\mu(F)$. Absurd by integrability of $f$.

Another way is to consider your $F_n$, noticing that their intersection gives $F$, ie: the decreasing limit of $F_n$ is $F$, and to use Markov inequality and the continuity of the measure.

So you can see that there is no "big idea" behind... well i think.